# reserva vs. reservación

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos

What is the difference between *reserva* and *reservación* (as in a reservation that you would make at a restaurant)? Do the two words mean the same thing? Which is used in what parts of the Spanish-speaking world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to RAE, they're pretty much the same in that sense, I would say. But I've never heard "reservación" in Spain, really.

Comment: In Chile "reservación" isn't used either.

Comment: In Colombia both forms are used.